# Custom jquery/js slider animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Looking for way to build custom jquery/js slider:
[image]
Example direction from left to right:

```
<div id="slider">
   <div class="item"> Left fade in 1</div>
   <div class="item"> Left fade in 2</div>
   <div class="item"> At center 1</div>
   <div class="item"> At center 2</div>
   <div class="item"> At center 3</div>
   <div class="item"> Right fade out 1</div>
   <div class="item"> Right fade out 2</div>
</div>
```

3 elements at center, 2 elements at each side make animate with fade in/out..

Maybe someone can give some sample how to write it?
Regards.

Comment: Great sketch :).   Maybe [this](https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+carousel&) or [this](https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+3d+carousel) helps you?

Comment: Remove the part where you say you are looking for a lib/tutorial. That isn't really allowed in a question on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [slickslider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and use transform to transform the edges.
I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsc0ftvz/2/) that shows the idea of what i mean.  Maybe it can help you on the right way.

```
.item.left
{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(45deg) scale(0.8);
}

.item.right
{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-45deg) scale(0.8);
}
```